# Import a simple library from maven

Tags: java

I generated a Webservice Axis2 Client using a wsdl.

Most of the code works well I have a couple of errors missing dependencies.

```
org.apache.axis2.client.Stub
org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation
org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperation
org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext
... and a lot more
```

For example `org.apache.axis.databinding` is working

I have this axis2 dependencies on my pom.xml

But somehow I am missing dependencies.

```
<properties>
    <axis2.version>1.6.4</axis2.version>
</properties>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
        <version>${axis2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
        <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
                <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${axis2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
        <version>${axis2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: All classes above are part of axis2-kernel. Why are you using an outdated version of Axis2?

Comment: Because it's what required by my PM. That's not the problem. Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: @user10628262 What is the full error message you get when you run the maven build process?

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2.wso2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1.wso2v10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-base</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

You just forgot to enclose them within `<dependencies></dependencies>`. Just add these dependencies in your pom.xml and if you need more axis2 dependencies, just go the https://mvnrepository.com to look for more dependencies of axis2 and add them in your pom.xml, according to the version you are using.

Comment: Could not find artifact org.apache.axis2.wso2:axis2-client:pom:1.6.1.wso2v10 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)